# Android Source download

Tags: android, git, android-source

Hey guys I am new to porting android os. I am trying to download android source and wanted to know which git repository should I download for kitkat. And alos I want to download the source in GIT windows as I do not want to use linux terminal and repo for downloading the source. 
Also, will downnloading https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+/android-msm-hammerhead-3.4-kk-r1 give me the source or will https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/master give me the source?
Note: I have a very limited download limit at high speeds so I only want to download the relevant source files. No prebuilt Images or and device Images. I just want to download the source for stock kitkat android and use it in ubuntu for further building.

Comment: "I do not want to use linux terminal and repo for downloading the source" -- you are welcome to download [the source to **`repo`**](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo) and attempt to replicate that ~23KB of Python via some sort of GUI operation. I have no idea if this is possible, as developers should use **`repo`** per [the instructions](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html).

Comment: yes I've read the instructions and from what I've read on the net the actual source is pretty smaller that the repo downloads, some guy over the net download 4.1.2 for 1GB(excluding prebuilts etc.) and what repo was downloading for me(4.4) was 8GB. That difference. How am I then supposed to then download only the relevant file for the 4.4 os

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you don't understand the organization of the Android source.  It is a forest of git repositories, maintained, as CommonsWare says, with a tool called "repo".  Theoretically, you could clone each of the, approximately, 450 git repos, separately.  I suspect it would be pretty hard to do.

When you download the source, you will get all of the versions, tagged appropriately.  You need only checkout at the right tag.

Comment: ok I get what you're trying to say so I'll have to download all the 450 GIT repositories? I have already downloaded the msm one, so what is it? is it a source for 4.4 or just a pre made ready to be compressed and flashed rom?

Comment: It is none of those things.  It is the source for an Android enabled Linux kernel for a Qualcomm chipset.  It has nothing to do with the source for Android.

Comment: So it is completely useless for building for a new device? and I will have to use repo sync to get the repository?

Comment: Thank you good sir, I finally understand GIT shit and Android shit and both their shits put together, REPO is a simple script that reads the manifest file of a project that you want to download with init, with repo sync it downloads all relevant files to that specific project(in our case build). Now the only problem is which files are actually required for a successful build of android os. I will tear through the files make a normal list of files that I will be needing and make a new zip and share. Thanks folks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try github, to download zip files of the branch you require. It also seems to have android kernel files, but you need to search for what you need.

The android kernel msm (for qualcomm) source code
https://github.com/android/kernel_msm

The android source code
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base

The website says it is a mirror of the google server. Which means it should work.